# use specified one from multiple oracle environments

Tags: oracle, occi

i have a Windows Server on which there is already a Oracle 10g(10.2.0.1) databases.
I would like to install a Oracle Instant Client(10.2.0.3 )  on it(because our program need link to those libraries).
So there are two oracle environments now,my question is how to make sure that  my program always use the second oracle environment(Instant Client)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the ORACLE_HOME, to your required environment im Windows Server.!